# onOptionsItemSelected dialog.show() not showing

Tags: android, android-menu

im trying to show a dialog box, that notify user upon success logout. currently the dialog box show only after processing the onOptionsItemSelected method. i would like to run the dialog box during or in onOptionsItemSelected.

I've googled and tried on "this", "MainActivity.this", "break", "return true". still not working yet. Please advice.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case LOGOUT_ID: {
            //run some logout process 
            // ........................
            //show message
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.setMessage("Successfully logged out");
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new   
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                 redirectToLoginPage();}
            });
            dialog.show();  
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I hope you don't finish the activity while doing the logout process.

Comment: what do you do in your logout process?

Comment: may be you should post your `onCreateOptionsMenu` method and the menu layout..

Comment: I guess that you want to show dialog before the logout job finished? If that true, I think just move the show dialog code to above of `//run some logout process` may works

Comment: @Modge i set an object of custom application context to null in that process

Comment: @Minhtdh //run some logout process is only setting the custom application context to null. i want to show the dialog box after the setting.

Comment: sorry guys the actual dialog is actually not in the case block its being called from an event triggering(this one not work). and when i run above code. it works fine. sorry for troubling!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
     case LOGOUT_ID: 
        doLogOut();
         break;

      default:
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}




private void showAlertDialogLogOut() {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Logout");
    dialog.setMessage("Successfully loged out");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
           redirectToLoginPage()
        }
    });
    dialog.show();

}

private void doLogOut() {

    // Do your job and when finish show the dialog
    showAlertDialogLogOut();
}
```